Altium schematic templates not showing up correctly when applied to schematic
I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question, but I haven't been able to get any help from Altium support and have been trying to solve this for quite a while.
I've created 2 schematic templates in Altium that I want to use. One is size A2 and one is A3. When I view the templates in the editor, they both look right. But when I apply either of them to a schematic, it also includes the standard Altium title block which I can't remove. Here are some images to illustrate the problem.
For the A3 Template, this is how it looks when viewed in the template editor:

This is how it looks when applied to a schematic:

It shows up with that additional title block and border, and I can't seem to remove it.
For the A2 Template, this is how it looks when viewed in the template editor:

This is how it looks when applied to a schematic:

This one is the same issue but because the size is the same as the additional border and title block, they actually overlap.
I've gone through most of the relevant documents on Altium's website but still haven't been able to figure out how to get the actual schematic to look like the template without the extra border and title block, and any help with this would be greatly appreciated!
This is in Altium Designer Version 24.3.1

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

After much time spent with Altium support, it turns out that this issue was actually caused by a known bug in Altium Designer.
The support agent provided me with a workaround solution to use until the bug is fixed, which solved the problem for me.
The instructions provided were:

Save the corrupted *.schdot  as ASCII *.schdoc
Open it in a text editor, delete all lines with ‘OWNERINDEX=1’

For me, this was just the entire first line of the document


Save the file with the original *.schdot extension
Open the file in Altium Designer and it should work

Note that for me, I had to reapply all my changes to the template (change the sizing and updating title block), but after doing this the template worked.
Unfortunately they didn't say when this bug would be fixed, but I hope this helps someone who runs into the same issue!

Could you please add the version of AD to your original question so that it's more helpful?

@SpehroPefhany Sure, added

Thank you, it fixed the issue! The bug is still there. I'm on 24.7.2.
